# extract content between all paragraph tags

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

How do I extract only the content between all of the `<p></p>` tags in a given string? I know preg_match or regex but I spent hours already trying to put this stuff together. thought I'd just ask. simple question and a simple answer i hope. Thanks in advance. this would be in PHP, btw.

Comment: Ahem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: it doesn't have to be regex, i just need to know how to go about doing this.

Comment: `I know preg_match or regex but I spent hours already trying to put this stuff together` so whats the question? do you want to use regex or use DOM

Comment: i just need to get it done. i just need a simple code that extracts only what is between the p tags in a string of html, and i need to know how to build something similiar on my own for future reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[DOMDocument::loadHTML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php). Maybe not the fastest option, but should be simple.

Something like (it's been a while since I've actually written PHP...):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($string);
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('p') as $paragraph) {
    // do something with $paragraph->textContent
}
```